# querydsl get column from tuple

Tags: java, querydsl

I've created query that returns building id and apartments count in that building.
How to get buildings with max count from this tuple? Other than iterate through entire list.

```
JPAQuery<Tuple> query2 = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
QBuildingEntity building = QBuildingEntity.buildingEntity;
QApartmentEntity apartment = QApartmentEntity.apartmentEntity;
query2 = query2.select(apartment.count(), apartment.building.id).from(apartment).where(apartment.status.lower().eq("free"))
                .groupBy(apartment.building);
```

Here are building and apartment entities:

```
public class BuildingEntity extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "building", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    Set<ApartmentEntity> apartments = new HashSet<>();
}

public class ApartmentEntity extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    @Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false, length = 50)
    String status;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "BUILDING_ID")
    BuildingEntity building;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could order the query by `apartment.count()` in descending order and pick the first result. Something like:

```
query2.select(apartment.count(), apartment.building.id)
      .from(apartment)
      .where(apartment.status.lower().eq("free"))
      .groupBy(apartment.building)
      .orderBy(apartment.count().desc())
      .limit(1L);
```